# Use page-specific CSS in plone

Tags: css, plone

Is there a way that I can define css so that, for example all paragraphs (<p>) on this specific page are formated according to that css, but not other pages on the plone site?

Inline-css does work, but that's pretty annoying for larger tables I'd like to style.

Comment: Does your body class or html have different classes on each page?

Comment: Is it sufficient having CSS per portal-type or per-template or do you need individual styling for each page?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have access to the configuration. If that would be a possibility, I could ask our administrator to have a specific class for this page, but a solution that doesn't require admin privileges would be best.

Comment: Individual styling would be necessary I guess.

Comment: You may use some customized pre-defined TinyMCE styles for your needs but you don't want allow arbitrary markup and styles the be allowed for every editor. They will mess up your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

- ploneCustom.css or related custom CSS file which is merged with other CSS files in portal_css registry
- Use `<body>` CSS classes to target a single page only

More `<body>` CSS can be added for custom needs. What kind of page you need to target with CSS.

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates_css_and_javascripts/css.html#adding-new-css-body-classes

Also you can include CSS as `<head>` viewlet if needed but this approach is not recommended.

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views/viewlets.html#viewlets-for-one-page-only

Comment: Thanks! Your answer lead me to this page which works perfectly: 
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.CustomOverrides

Comment: I found the following rule from [this blog post](http://blog.dbain.com/2011/11/common-diazo-rules-for-plone.html) helpful for implementing this strategy: `<!-- BODY THEME (inject body classes from Plone into the theme) --> <copy attributes="*" css:theme="body" css:content="body" />`